# Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 Dual boot, Grub not showing!

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside with Windows 7. Everything is fine until i want to enter Ubuntu. When I start my pc, after normal boot, there is no Grub or OS Selection menu, and my system loads straight into Windows 7.

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Temporary Solution

When you start your pc keep `Left Shift` pressed. it will show you the grub

### Permanent solution

If you get to start ubuntu by the temp soln then to make boot permanently show the grub-
Open startup manager(install it if it isnt installed from sofware center)

Change the value for timeout- pref 5 - 10 secs

Default OS - Whatever you want

[image]

Rest leave everything as it(you can edit that if you want to)
if that does not work install `boot-repair` via ppa

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install boot-repair

This worked for me should work for you too

Answer (score 1):

you can try this where 'j' is your iso image
go to start menu run enter the command below

```
J:\wubi.exe --force-wubi
```

Comment: this i already told you in your asked question
http://askubuntu.com/questions/148452/no-grub-menu-after-installing-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

read this
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
and then put ur ubuntu installation disk in and boot in trial mode, revist the page [google boot repair] and then open terminal and copy paste the commands and then it should auto start up, then hit recomended repair and reboot 2 test, if that doesnt work then try again but go into advance and change ur boot so it boots into grub and then if it still dont work... blah

Comment: @ThomsBell If you do use the `Boot-Repair` tool and it displays a message with a URL that looks like `http://paste.ubuntu.com/123456/` then **remember it** for possible future reference. The link contains information about how your system boot is configured that could be of use if your system is still not booting the way you prefer/need it to.