# Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 dual boot, GRUB menu not showing

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I have Windows 7 Home premium 64bit installed on my laptop, Now I have installed Ubuntu Desktop 13.04 from bootable flash but Ubuntu GRUB menu not showing.

When I start my PC, after normal boot, there is no GRUB or OS Selection menu and my system loads straight into Windows 7.

I selected *"Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7"* then from *"advance partitioning tool"* I selected different drives for Ubuntu `root` and `swap`.

If I run Ubuntu installer again it says you already have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 on your system.

[Edit]
I read it in ubuntu help that
In the drop-down under Device for boot loader installation:
Never choose any other partition! (this may break the boot of your other systems [Bug #1049549](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1049549))
see img [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=g2_installing_partition.png)
So i deleted my / drive and installed ubuntu again with this configuration, its working fine now. Thanks to all for answering.

Comment: What happens if you leave the USB flash in and reboot?

Comment: in USB live CD do sudo grub-install then sudo update-grub and reboot. And give feedback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boot up a live usb and try to repair the bootloader with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

After installing 'boot-repair' launch this program from dash by searching for the term and click its icon to launch it.

If this doesn't work then boot into Windows 7, download and install a freeware called 'EasyBCD' (latest version is 2.2)

After installing this tool, select 'add new entry' column and install grub under the Linux tab.

Sorry I'm on my phone now so I can't add links and pictures to the post. I'll surely edit this post today when I get to the house

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have solved my problem read edit portion of my Question. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: It's still best to choose the best suited answer to close this question

Comment: the easybcd is paid softwere?

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo "freeware"

Answer (score 0):

[Dual boot 12.04/windows 7 After installation my computer reboots straight to Windows. There is no option to boot Ubuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145335/dual-boot-12-04-windows-7-after-installation-my-computer-reboots-straight-to-win?rq=1)

[Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 Dual boot, Grub not showing!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128233/windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-04-dual-boot-grub-not-showing?rq=1)

Aternatively make a grub disk to boot the first time.

Comment: I have solved my problem read edit portion of my Question. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Mysterio's solution above worked for me. I tried it last night.

To provide more detailed step-by-step instructions, here they are:

1. Download the Ubuntu iso.
2. Burn it to a USB flash drive.
3. Ensure your computer boots to USB (this can be done via the BIOS).
4. With your Ubuntu USB inserted, boot up your computer.
5. You will be prompted with Ubuntu asking if you want to install Ubuntu or launch Ubuntu via the USB.
6. Choose to launch Ubuntu via the USB.
7. Once you're in Ubuntu, open the terminal.
8. In the terminal, type in the commands as mentioned by Mysterio:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install boot-repair
   ```
9. Follow the boot repair instructions.
10. Once done with the repair process, reboot.
11. Once Ubuntu shuts down to reboot, remove your Ubuntu USB from your computer.
12. Once your computer starts up, you should see the Grub bootloader.