# No bootloader menu after attempting to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I wanted to use Ubuntu alongside my Windows 7, so I installed it from a USB. During installation, it **didn't** detect my existing Windows. So, I chose "**Something Else**". From there, I formatted a drive with settings:

Size: 20 Gb

type: primary partition,

file system: ext4.

and mount point: ""

Then I allocated 4GB extra for "swap".

Then I installed Ubuntu and it completed smoothly. Then it asked me to reboot. After rebooting, I was expecting a menu to choose between Linux and Windows, but I didn't get any menu at all. My Windows booted normally.

What do I need to configure to get my dual boot system working?

Comment: This link may be of help to you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/288396/windows-7-and-ubuntu-13-04-dual-boot-grub-menu-not-showing?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. This happened to me when I installed Ubuntu myself. the "menu" you're talking about is called a "bootloader". The "windows boot loader" does not detect anything but windows. That's why Ubuntu *should* install "grub" which detects Ubuntu and will detect windows.

Now to install grub you need the Ubuntu live usb again. Boot the computer from it

...then you have two options; one is getting a program from the internet that does the whole trick. It's called boot repair. It's the easy choice. You can follow the link commented by vivid_vibe [Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 dual boot, GRUB menu not showing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288396/windows-7-and-ubuntu-13-04-dual-boot-grub-menu-not-showing?rq=1)

or if *for example* you have trouble connecting to the internet then there are a set of instructions that you can do manually from a terminal to fix the problem but it's not as easy as the program . Here's how to do it [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

feed me back

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the USB again into Ubuntu and follow the instructions below:

Open Terminal, and type:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev && sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts && sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc && sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sdX
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX 
update-grub
exit && sudo umount /mnt/dev && sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts && sudo umount /mnt/proc && sudo umount /mnt/sys && sudo umount /mnt
```

Where `/dev/sdX` is your partition, like `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb`.