# Ubuntu 13.04 and Windows 8 dual boot problem where Windows 8 doesn't boot

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, windows-8, boot-partition

I will brief about the problem, that how it started.

- I purchased a Sony VAIO (SVE15133CNW) laptop on May-2013, with pre-installed Windows 8
- After couple of days I installed Ubuntu 13.04 using    USB in a dual
  boot mode; Both were working fine for few weeks
- One day, while the Ubuntu shutdown was still in progress,
  I closed the lid (I did this before as well many
  times); But this time it did some corruption
- While next starting up, it directly booted to Windows 8 and that
  happened repeatedly. The GRUB menu never really appeared. During
  trying to fix it, I hard shut down Windows 8 few times. I posted a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312591/in-dual-boot-pc-the-boot-grub-menu-suddenly-disappeared-ubuntu-option-is-not-a) as well
- Then, I tried with "Boot repair" tool and finally the GRUB was back,
  I was able to login to Ubuntu without any problem
- Unfortunately, Windows 8 would never really boot after that; It will
  do some auto repair stuff and then give an error and then go back to
  the GRUB menu.

After searching numerous forums, there is no luck (from this forum too, I tried many suggestions which also include [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported/228069#228069) and [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233687/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-along-windows-8)). I tried every possible option, like editing the Windows 8 entry by pressing "E" and changing the current gpt3 into gpt1 till gpt8. But it always gives the [same error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221311/grub-errors-during-uefi-dual-boot-for-windows-8-cant-find-command-drivemap):

> can't find command 'drivemap'
>   invalid EFI file path

At the max after repairing, it reaches to the error which points out to [0xc000021a](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-system/windows-8-pro-cannot-boot-error-0xc000021a/ebf26ca7-e594-4c56-bbe0-cca43dfe5978).

For many days, I am in this situation. If someone can fix this, I would be really thankful. :)
On other side, I don't have much data in Windows 8, but have lots in Ubuntu. As a final resolution, is there a way by which I can re-install Windows 8 without affecting Ubuntu partition?

I can still access Windows memory inside Ubuntu and here are some of the files which are appearing under "C:\Windows\System32\Logfiles\Srt":

- [SrtTrail.txt](http://pastebin.com/ZJffa5Nq).
- [disklayout.txt](http://pastebin.com/q7wV1vyC)
- [bcdinfo.txt](http://pastebin.com/ujukNCVf)

Please let me know if something more is needed.

This is the latest result in pastebin of running [boot repair in ubuntu](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5959354/).
Here are some of the photos if they help:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]